# jQuery Dynamic Selector and Element

Tags: jquery, jquery-tools

**jsFiddle Full Code:** http://jsfiddle.net/bvmdW/

I used jQuery Embedly to replace YouTube links with thumbnail and videos. I hide the videos part using `display:none` in CSS. The Embedly script will dynamically create the following DOM during the process:

```
<li id="1">
    <img rel="vidPreview-1" class="embedly" src=".....">
    <div id="vidPreview-1" class="vidPreview"> iframe videos here </div>
</li>
<li id="1">
    <img rel="vidPreview-2" class="embedly" src=".....">
    <div id="vidPreview-2" class="vidPreview"> iframe videos here </div>
</li>
```

Both `<img rel="vidPreview-X"` and `<div id="vidPreview-X` are dynamically generated by Embedly.

Now, I'll also use [jQueryTools Overlay](http://flowplayer.org/tools/overlay/index.html) plugin to popup the hidden videos upon clicking the thumbnail. I used:

```
$("img[rel]").live('click', function () {
    $(this).overlay().load();
});
```

but it seems the Overlay plugin doesn't recognize `live()`. In Firebug it says that: `uncaught exception: Could not find Overlay: vidPreview-X`

Can someone please guide me how to make a `live()` with jQueryTools Overlay?

Comment: From this page example i found that You missed # in rel="vidPreview-1".Please check it or forget to post it here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In img tag you missed # in rel attribute.Please add # to the rel attr value.Check again.

```
 <li id="1">
     <img rel="#vidPreview-1" class="embedly" src=".....">
     <div id="vidPreview-1" class="vidPreview"> iframe videos here </div> </li> <li id="1">
     <img rel="#vidPreview-2" class="embedly" src=".....">
    <div id="vidPreview-2" class="vidPreview"> iframe videos here </div> </li>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, it works now in modern browsers. However, it won't work in IE8 and IE7, it still shows and error: `Error: Exception thrown and not caught`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but try to use delegate function http://api.jquery.com/delegate/
I've faced with strange behavior of `live` for a few times.

Comment: "As of jQuery 1.7, the .live() method is deprecated. Use .on() to attach event handlers. Users of older versions of jQuery should use .delegate() in preference to .live()." http://api.jquery.com/live/